# Excel formula - Get first occurrence of partial string in rows above cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of fruits in Excel 2013.

[image]

I'd like to fill the "Category" column by searching from the current row to the top until the first occurrence of "::", which is the keyword for a category in the table.

If there was some way to reverse a range, I could do something like "=Match("::*"; $A6:$A$2)" to find the row. However, this is not possible.

Does anyone know how this might be accomplished using formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your provided sample data, and assuming your data is already organized as shown in your sample, you can take advantage of that organization and use this formula in cell C2 and copy down:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,2)="::","",IF(LEFT(A1,2)="::",MID(A1,4,LEN(A1)),C1))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great method. Very clever! I ended up using this method in my solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is in A1, put this in C3:

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE (14,6,ROW($A$1:A2)/(LEFT($A$1:A2,2)="::"),1))
```

And copy down.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a kinda different approach. I'm just basically responding to this part of your post to prove this is possible:

> If there was some way to reverse a range, I could do something like "=Match("::*"; $A6:$A$2)" to find the row. However, this is not possible.

Reversing a range is possible, it's just tricky.

As you pointed out: `$A6:$A$2` won't work since this is equivalent to `$A$2:$A6`.

However, without getting into the nitty-gritty details, this array formula will reverse this range:

```
= INDEX($A$2:$A6,N(IF({1},MAX(ROW($A$2:$A6))-ROW($A$2:$A6)+1)))
```

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this formula into a cell.

You could use this in combination with your `MATCH` formula to get the desired result (which tells you how many rows up the `::` row is):

```
= MATCH("::*",INDEX($A$2:$A6,N(IF({1},MAX(ROW($A$2:$A6))-ROW($A$2:$A6)+1))),0)
```

(Also haha this is kinda cool: Usually you see `MATCH` used within `INDEX` to effectively get a `VLOOKUP` type of functionality. This is the first time I have ever seen it the opposite way of having `INDEX` within `MATCH`.)

Note that I'm not saying this is necessarily the best approach for this specific problem, just proving a point that arrays can be reversed.